# Can I move the file pointer to a particular (byte) location in a formatted file?

Tags: fortran

I'm reading a formatted ascii file.  The file is essentially encoded ascii and looks something like this:

```
fieldname 1
header info 1
header info 2
header info 3
aruieopaurjjk&*(^0uio3789$
#$adsfhoueraeiknvaer93-8(&897klfaicvnjai9ea890 34
*(()kla3j90ajkl4a8 ...

fieldname 2
header info 1
header info 2
header info 3
8&80973jknaua890a3a()Ujkl;fjaoi0()8&*(&jla;f)*(
jkl;aje()()78907jkoja0988093jn890&*(4fakoa343a
...
```

So, while the files are ascii, they're not human readable.  The record lengths are not consistent.  I have routines to read the data assuming that the file pointer is positioned right before `fieldname`.  It checks to make sure the fieldname is the one I want and reads/decodes that field returning the data.  If the field isn't the one I want, it reads lines until it comes to a `fieldname` line.  As you can imagine, this is terribly inefficient.  To read the last field, I essentially need to read every other field sequentially.  Also, If I read them out of order, I need to rewind the entire file and start again.  What I would like to do is create an index such that I can map fieldnames to byte offsets from the start of a file.  That way, I can just "seek" to the right location in the file and continue reading as a formatted sequential file...

I'm happy with any solution that will allow me to read the file in the following way:

```
read(iu,'(A)',end=190) mystring  !get from current position to end of line
read(iu,*,end=190) myint1,myint2 !read two integers
read(iu,'(a,i8,3e14.7,i8,a)',end=190, err=900) !read a string, 8 character wide integer ...
```

I could probably even live with a solution which has some sort of optimized `getline` function and stream access.  Then I could just replace the above with calls to getline followed by a read of the string that is returned ...

I've looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110616/fortran-how-to-write-data-to-specific-line-in-the-file), however my question is slightly more general (That post wanted a line number.  I want a byte offset).  It seems like this could be accomplished via some magic using stream access and the pos specifier, but I'm not sure if that would force me to rewrite the reader entirely (which is nearly impossible since I don't have any idea how the reader actually transforms the seemingly random strings into floats).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formatted stream access (introduced in the Fortran 2003 standard) allows you to seek to a position in the file that has been previously read.  Because formatted stream still has a record based approach (formally using a newline as the record delimiter) often the same code used for formatted sequential access can be reused.

You obtain the current file position using an INQUIRE statement:

```
INTEGER :: file_pos
INQUIRE(UNIT=iu, POS=file_pos)
```

You could call INQUIRE in this manner prior to the READ of the record that contains each `fieldname` line, then read that record, determine what the fieldname is for that record and store the fieldname and file position in an array or similar for later lookup.

You can reposition to a previously stored position using a non-advancing READ:

```
READ (iu,"()", ADVANCE='NO', POS=file_pos)
```

Subsequent READ statements will then carry on as they would for sequential formatted files encountering the repositioned record for the first time.

Comment: Brilliant.  I'll give this a test.  Do you know if this feature is widely supported by common compilers these days?  (gfortran, pgf90, ifort, ... ?)

Comment: Recent ifort supports it - I know some bugs in earlier versions of 12.0 have been fixed.  Recent (June build) gfortran appears to have some support but with extant bugs.

Comment: @IanH is it possible to jump ahead a number of bytes and start reading/writing from there? I was thinking about `rewind(unit)` to go to the beginning and read a number of `character(len=1)`. This will take me to the desired place. However, how to start writing at that place? Open the file a `readwrite`?