# Directly read a particular line in fortran

Tags: file-io, fortran, fortran90

I want to read a particular line of a file, e.g. the 3rd line of the `input.dat` file. My present code :

```
Program Read_a_line
Implicit None
Integer:: i
Real*8:: x,y    

open (10, file='input.dat', status='old')

do i=1,3
  read (10,*) x, y 
end do

  print*,'x=',x,' y=',y



End Program Read_a_line
```

However, the code reads all the data till it reaches the 3rd line. Can we just read the 3rd line? Can we read several particular lines, eg. the 2nd and 4th lines only.

Online available examples do a similar trick. I was wondering if there exists a direct way in modern fortran version.

I'm a bit curious!

Comment: somewhat better to read "nothing" on the lines you want to ignore, `do i = 1,2 ; read(10,*) ; end do ; read (10,*) x, y` . This is not a fortran peculiarity by the way. You must do similar in most other languages that I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

if you have fixed size records you can seek to the correct point

see also [Can I move the file pointer to a particular (byte) location in a formatted file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779398/can-i-move-the-file-pointer-to-a-particular-byte-location-in-a-formatted-file)

Comment: Far simpler, if the file is formatted, to read two lines and ignore them.