# Fortran IO files

Tags: io, fortran

I am writing some procedures for IO in fortran.

Am getting a bit confused regarding formatted, unformatted, sequential and direct.

As I understand formatted files are human readable (normal txt files), whereas unformatted ones are machine readable.

For unformatted files, I can use either sequential or direct access.

Can I have direct access of formatted files.

Comment: formatted  direct access requires all i/o be done in fixed length records, which is usually a very cumbersome way to work unless you have some peculiar application. see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29708659/1004168  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have direct access of formatted files.

From the Fortran 2008 Standard, Cl. 9.3.3.3 "Direct access":

> 2 When connected for direct access, an external file has the following
>   properties.
>
> - [...]
> - **The records of the file are either all formatted or all unformatted.**
>     If the sequential access method is also a member of the set of allowed
>     access methods for the file, its endfile record, if any, is not
>     considered to be part of the file while it is connected for direct
>     access. If the sequential access method is not a member of the set of
>     allowed access methods for the file, the file shall not contain an
>     endfile record.

Comment: I would like some examples of writing and reading unformatted direct access files. I previously have been using sequential access. If I create a direct access unformatted file, will the data be readable from an editor, in other words, is it a normal text file?

Comment: No I can't. Still have to check what happens with direct access formatted files.