# Fortran : Is there a way to add vertical spacing in direct access files. Slash seems to not work

Tags: format, fortran, gfortran

The first issue was that I wanted to make a file and after some computations to change a value in the center of the file. Hence sequential access doesn't work. Finally I made a progress with the direct access but everything is printed in a line but I want it one under the other. I tried slash '/' but it doesn't work. Is there any idea?

My code is :

```
   open (unit=2125, file='out.neo_to_gs2_2', status='replace', &
         access='direct', form='formatted', recl=100)
   write(2125,'(a16,2es16.8)',rec=1) 'mach =', mach, mach_new(ir_loc,2)
   write(2125,777, rec=3) 'dmach_ir_loc =', dmach_ir_loc, 'g_exb =', &
                          g_exb, -(rhoc/qinp)*dmach_ir_loc(2)
   write(2125,778, rec=4) 'ntheta =', ntheta, 'ntg_out =', ntg_out, 'ir_loc =', ir_loc
```

The result is a line with all the information :

```
mach =  6.43167496E-03    -8.57318202E-05                                                          mach_lab =  6.47227491E-03 -8.65502010E-05                                                      dmach_ir_loc = -2.32641799E-02  1.90173879E-04         g_exb =  9.40463050E-03 -7.68784920E-05            ntheta = 32       ntg_out = 16        ir_loc =  3
```

but I want it to be like this :

```
        mach =  6.43167496E-03 -8.57318202E-05
    mach_lab =  6.47227491E-03 -8.65502010E-05
dmach_ir_loc = -2.32641799E-02  1.90173879E-04
       g_exb =  9.40463050E-03 -7.68784920E-05
      ntheta = 32
     ntg_out = 16
      ir_loc =  3
```

Somewhere else in the code I've written the second record

```
       write(2125,'(a16,2es16.8)', rec=2) 'mach_lab =', mach_lab                      !wladimir
```

Comment: Show your code and the desired output.

Comment: You could manually add leading spaces to the strings... Or, use [`ADJUSTR`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.0/gfortran/ADJUSTR.html).

Comment: With direct access you need to explicitly write the line end characters in the record. This is `char(10)` if I recall.  Note you need to put it right at the end of the record (column 100).

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/29708659/1004168 ( and this can probably be marked as a dup.)

Comment: thank you for your help. I add char(10) at every end of my write command. There was a need of some kind manipulation to put it right at the end. I'll add the solution just for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a fixed length string for the format specifier (here: `a15`, 15 characters):

```
program test
  write(*,'(a15,2es15.8)') 'mach = ', 6.43167496E-03, -8.57318202E-05
  write(*,'(a15,2es15.8)') 'mach_lab = ', 6.47227491E-03, -8.65502010E-05
  write(*,'(a15,2es15.8)') 'dmach_ir_loc = ', -2.32641799E-02,  1.90173879E-04
  write(*,'(a15,2es15.8)') 'g_exb = ', 9.40463050E-03, -7.68784920E-05
  write(*,'(a15,i2)') 'ntheta = ', 32
  write(*,'(a15,i2)') 'ntg_out = ', 16
  write(*,'(a15,i2)') 'ir_loc = ', 3
end program
```

This results in:

```
        mach =  6.43167505E-03-8.57318228E-05
    mach_lab =  6.47227513E-03-8.65502006E-05
dmach_ir_loc = -2.32641790E-02 1.90173872E-04
       g_exb =  9.40463040E-03-7.68784885E-05
      ntheta = 32
     ntg_out = 16
      ir_loc =  3
```

Answer (score 1):

the solution is :

```
   open (unit=2125, file='out.neo_to_gs2_2', status='replace', &
         access='direct', form='formatted', recl=49)
   write(2125,777,rec=1) 'mach =', mach, mach_new(ir_loc,2), char(10)
   write(2125,777,rec=3) 'dmach_ir_loc =', dmach_ir_loc, char(10)
   write(2125,777,rec=4) 'g_exb =', g_exb, -(rhoc/qinp)*dmach_ir_loc(2), char(10)
   write(2125,778,rec=5) 'ntheta =', ntheta, '', char(10)
   write(2125,778,rec=6) 'ntg_out =', ntg_out, '', char(10)
   write(2125,778,rec=7) 'ir_loc =', ir_loc, ''

777 format(a16,2es16.8,a)
778 format(a16,i3,a29,a)

write(2125,'(a16,2es16.8,a)', rec=2) 'mach_lab =', mach_lab,char(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to add this as a character in your write list, either the last or the first.

```
NEW_LINE('A')
```

Comment: Which is on common platforms equal to `achar(10)` and also `char(10)` on ASCII based platforms (actually all that support such a new thing as `new_line()`.