# Writing to the .txt file in specific format

Tags: fortran, gfortran

This is my code:

```
Program NN_Lenght

Implicit none

Integer::i,j
Integer,parameter::Br_Dio=14,Br_NN_Mre=10
Integer,parameter,dimension(Br_Dio,Br_NN_Mre)::Lenght=50
Character(350),parameter::fmtA_0_0='(/,1x,130("-"),/,1x,"LENGHT VALUES NN DM:",/,1x,130("-"))'
Character(350),parameter::fmtA_0_1='(1x,"Network:",1x,10(1x,"||NN_DN",1x,i0,"||"))'
Character(350),parameter::fmtA_0_2='(1x,130("-"))'
Character(350),parameter::fmtA_0_3='(1x,"Dio:",1x,i2,".",2x,9("||",7x,"||",1x),"||",8x,"||",1x,/,1x,130("-"))'

Open(Unit=15,File='Lenght_values_NN.txt',Status='Unknown')

   Write(15,trim(adjustl(fmtA_0_0)))
   Write(15,trim(adjustl(fmtA_0_1)))(j,j=1,Br_NN_Mre)
   Write(15,trim(adjustl(fmtA_0_2)))

   Do concurrent(i=1:Br_Dio)

      Write(15,trim(adjustl(fmtA_0_3)))i

   End Do

Close(Unit=15,Status='Keep')

End Program NN_Lenght
```

The result of code is `Lenght_values_NN.txt` file and in that file there is a table_matrix with empty fields(14x10). I want to enter in every empty field of table_matrix the value of Length. That value is 50, just like in variable definition part of the code. How to do that?

Comment: you do not want to pre-"format" a file and go back and overwrite parts, if that's what you are asking. Just write what you want in the first place.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29688290/1004168

Comment: How to keep content in `Lenght_values_NN.txt` afther using `Rewind(15)`?

Comment: the link in my prior comment shows how to do this. (For starters you can not rewind, you need to close and reopen in direct access mode). As said, its an overly cumbersome thing to do and really not recommended.